Stepping into functions results in an unknown file error
I am using Visual Studio Code on windows and I am trying to debug a very very simple Rust program, to learn how to properly use the gnu gdb. The issue is of course not on the program, which I report for reference:
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    let a = 12;
    let b = 16;
    let c;

    c = sum_two_integers(a, b);
    println!("Sum returned: {}", c);

    println!("End of Rust program...");
}

fn sum_two_integers (a:i32, b:i32) -> i32 {
    let c;
    c = a + b;

    println!("Sum computed: {}", c);
    
    return c;
}

The issue is with the gdb.exe: when I run it, both from VSCode or cmd line, it properly works only with F5/"continue", jumping in the breakpoints subsequently.
But, if for instance I put a breakpoint in the 1st main line
println!("Hello, world!");

and in that point I use F11/"step" (the "step-into" command), it pops-up a file which is not found (here the print from VSCode):
vscode: gdb searches for a not-existing file
This occurs since I clicked F11/"step" instead of F10/"next", which for a newbie could be logical. But whenever I use the the same debugger for a C/C++ program, it would simply jump to the next line.
So the question is: has anyone faced the same issue? Does someone know if there could be some additional commands to the gdb that could avoid this issue with Rust programs?
It is not a very very big issue, I can continue with breakpoints and I can handle it, but it is quite annoying every time distinguish the F10 from the F11 command.
This occurs also if I set with rustup the msvc toolchain and try to debug with VSCode with the msvc. Same issue.. Just for completeness, these are my toolchains and I set the gnu as default:
PS C:\SwDev\Sw\01_Attempts\C++\VSCode\VSCode_Rust_gdb_01> rustup toolchain list
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu (default)
stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc


This happens because in the debug info, when encoding stdlib, instead of putting the paths to its source the compiler puts a path of the file relative to /rustc/<rustc_version_hash>.
I don't know a way to change that globally and this is really annoying, but for a specific project, you can map this prefix to the real directory of stdlib source code (you need to have the rust-src rustup component installed).
Save the hash the window you faced shows, and in your debug configuration, add the following property:
For MSVC and I believe also gdb:
"sourceFileMap": {
    "/rustc/<your_hash>": "<your_home>/.rustup/toolchains/<project_toolchain>/lib/rustlib/src/rust"
}

For LLDB:
"sourceMap": {
    "/rustc/<your_hash>": "<your_home>/.rustup/toolchains/<project_toolchain>/lib/rustlib/src/rust"
}

There is also a setting rust-analyzer.debug.sourceFileMap that is supposed to do the same for rust-analyzer's debug lens, but I couldn't get it to work.

But if I remember well, multiple non-existing files were displayed on VSCode as I moved on with the debugging. My doubt is: how do I know how many files will be created and with how much data will they be filled-in? I would like to avoid to create, if possible, many files that could someday lead to other issues. My main concern is that I could do operations "without knowing what I am doing" (which is actually the truth :D). Do you know if in general the number of hashes is fixed or could increment with other dedug sessions?

@mgrs_ Those files are all part of the stdlib, the single mapping I showed should be enough.

Ok, I'll try asap. Many thanks!
